# What is the command to publish using SqlPackage.exe (DACPAC) using AAD MFA authentication?

Tags: dacpac, multi-factor-authentication

What is the command to publish using SqlPackage.exe using Azure Active Directory Multi-Factor Authentication authentication?

I tried

```
/ua /tid:<TenantId Guid>
```

but it does not work and gives error

```
Login failed for user ''.
```

I don't know how to specify the username 'foo@bar.com'. /TargetUser is only for SQL Auth.

Link to doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to download the MSI version of the SQL Package.exe from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15

You will find the sqlpackage.exe located here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin
```

Then the following command line works.

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /tsn:"<YourSQL.database.windows.net>" /sf:C:\DB\bin\Debug\YourDB.dacpac /tdn:<YourDatabase> /ua /tid:<Guid>
```

It should popup a UI to get the credentials. When I used the .net Core version, it did not popup the UI for credentials.

Comment: What a life-saver!  So glad you published this answer.  installing via the MSI fixed it for us too

Comment: How do you automate this so you don't need to go through an Interactive Pop-up?

Comment: I was using the dotnet tool as well. I was wondering why it didn't worked at all. I downloaded the msi, added the installation path into the Path of the system and now it works.  Thanks